# Initialize large i8 array using a small string in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to initialize a large array of `i8` in LLVM IR with a small string. I would like to do something like this:

```
@str = [1024 x i8] c"Hello World!\0A\00"
```

Notice that the string length is only 14 (or 13 if you don't count the null byte) . I don't care what gets put into the remaining bytes for now. The above code does not work due to `constant expression type mismatch` since the initializer array size does not match the destination array size. One solution would be to emit a correct number of `\00`s after the string, but I don't want to do that as it would lead to a lot of useless garbage. Is there a shortcut that I can take or will I have to perform a two step process of allocating the space for the string and then copying a string constant to it? If I do need to perform such a copy, what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LLVM IR, a global variable definition [has to be initialized](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables). For array initialization, the [array constant](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#complex-constants) has to match  the size of the array. I thus see no way to initialize the array in one step without having the trailing zeroes.

You can, however, use `zeroinitializer` to initialize the I8 array with zeroes and then use `strncpy` or `memcpy` to copy the small string to it. You can write such a snippet in C and see how clang compiles it:

```
#include <string.h>

extern char str[1024] = "";

int main() {
    char* hello = "Hello World!";
    strncpy(str, hello, sizeof(str));
    return 0;
}
```

When using `clang -O3 -S -emit-llvm test2.c -o test.ll` the bitcode file should look similar to the following:

```
@str = global [1024 x i8] zeroinitializer, align 16
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [13 x i8] c"Hello World!\00", align 1

define i32 @main() nounwind uwtable {
  %1 = tail call i8* @strncpy(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([1024 x i8]* @str, i64 0, i64 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i64 1024) nounwind
  ret i32 0
}

declare i8* @strncpy(i8*, i8* nocapture, i64) nounwind
```